How about CameraSwitcher in Unity URP
When I modified the camera using the Rendering Debugger window, it did not display correctly on the Game view.
When I change the order of the CameraSwitcher array, if I mount the camera first, I can see the camera Angle change in the lower-right corner of the Scene, but I still can't map it to the Game view
